# Why is SSH not resolving this hostname?

Tags: domain-name-system, ssh

When I try to SSH to a host on the network named `storage`, I get a DNS resolution failure:

```
$ ssh storage
ssh: Could not resolve hostname storage: Name or service not known
```

But when I query DNS with host, it works

```
$ host storage
storage has address 192.168.20.103
```

How is it that `host` can find the IP but `ssh` cannot?

Comment: Start getting into the habit of using FQDNs everywhere. If this is the first problem you've had along these lines, you're extraordinarily fortunate. These can be really hairy to track down, and it won't be your last. Here's a hint: `storage` is a live top-level domain on the Internet.

Comment: Are you able to 'ssh' to 192.168.20.103?

Comment: Where have you define the hostname of 192.168.20.103? /etc/hosts?

Comment: Typing FQDNs is a pain. Aliasing "storage" to "storage.mydomain.com" in .ssh/config, on the other hand, is really handy.

Comment: @pjc50 I type `sto` and then hit Tab.

Comment: @orphans My wifi router adds the domain automatically.

Comment: really, so it does act like a DNS server also?
And what do you mean with "automatically"?

Comment: I mean when I allocate a static IP for a host, it also adds it to the resolver.

Answer (score 36):

`ssh` and `host` resolve names following completely different paths, so it is not surprising that they yield different results sometimes, especially when the name to resolve is not a FQDN (hence the suggestion to use FQDNs everywhere.)

You don’t mention anything about your OS and your system configuration, so I have to keep it general, with an eye on Linux: MacOS details are somewhat different, and Windows even more, but the general concepts are the same.

- `host` queries DNS, so basically it looks in `/etc/resolv.conf` and queries the servers listed there, possibly attaching a domain name if the hostname is not already fully qualified. It ignores every other possible source, but beware that these days many systems run a local caching DNS server (usually `dnsmasq`) which reads `/etc/hosts` and other sources before querying other DNS servers, so if `host` queries that local server, results from `/etc/hosts` can creep in.
- `ssh` follows its own path. I will describe what `openssh` does under Linux, other implementations differ. First it looks for *host nicknames* defined in config files (system-wide `/etc/ssh/ssh_config` and per-user `~/.ssh/config`), then it searches other sources in the order specified by the `hosts:` directive in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`. Say it is something like:

  ```
  hosts: files dns
  ```

  this means: look in `/etc/hosts` and then query the DNS (`/etc/resolv.conf` again). Other possible sources are the obsolete `nis` and `netinfo` services, LDAP, active directory, you name them.

To debug your particular case, you should follow the path your implementation of `ssh` follows and find out where it gets stuck.

Comment: ltrace/strace can give you hints at how ssh is actually trying to resolve the domain... and the closest-to-how-the-os-does it, command line dns tool is probably getent.

Comment: Your recommendation of changing `/etc/nsswitch.conf` to read `hosts: files dns` worked for me. Just as an interesting side note, I've set up several Raspberry Pis with Raspian Jessie the past few weeks, and they've all required this change.

Comment: Fedora 35 seems to have changed from `hosts:      files dns myhostname` to `hosts:      files myhostname mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns`. I'm assuming the new line means it will fail if `mdns4_minimal` can't find the name, skipping the rest, in my case I'm using a custom local domain and not `.local` so it will never find it

Comment: I had a similar problem with Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS and OpenSSH_8.9p1 Ubuntu-3, OpenSSL 3.0.2 15 Mar 2022 in combination with pulse secure VPN. My solution was changing the `hosts` line in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`: `hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=continue] resolve [!UNAVAIL=return] dns` to `hosts:          files mdns4_minimal [NOTFOUND=return] resolve dns`